# Unable to determine cost of a Quota Units for Youtube Data API

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

We are developing an application to upload videos from multiple users to a single Youtube channel. But we are unable to find any document for quota units that specifies the cost in dollars. The quota calculator is helpful and  provides great insight. But still no mention of exceeding quota cost.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: Please take note that by no way monetary costs have a place in a developer's documentation. For such kind of information you should use different sources/channels. E.g. write directly to Google.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been able to gather there is no cost to exceeding the quota, however your access to the API will be cut-off when you do so (for that project). There doesn't appear to be anyway to buy more quota units, however you can request more using using the form available on the Quota tab of the Developer Console. Keep in mind that it may take some time (I've heard of months) before you receive a response from the Google team.